# Rails views and submitting a post request to the "new" method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I have a rails view with automatically generated content that is pulled from an API. Essentially, from the index, I want the user to have the ability to submit a form that will do an action on that data. Thus I need to submit the form, and any information I need to pass on in that form.

The rails view data is populated using the following code:

```
<form>    
<table class="dataTable">
 <tr>
  <th><%= button_to "Add To-Do Lists", new_setting_path, :class => 'button regular', :method => "get", :style=>'float: left; position: relative; margin-bottom: 0px;' %><%= link_to "customize", new_setting_path, :method => "get", :style=>'float: left; position: relative; top: 5px;' %>
 </th>
<th><strong>Project Name</strong></th>
<th></th>
  <th></th>
  </tr>

  <% @todo_list_masters.each do |todo_list_master| %>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="<%= todo_list_master.id %>" value="Car"></td>
    <td><%= todo_list_master.name %></td>
    <td><a href="<%= raw todo_list_master.url %>">Open In Basecamp</a></td>
    <td><%= link_to "Set as Master", {:controller => :settings, :action => :basecamp_todolist_master, :basecamp_model_id => todo_list_master.id, :basecamp_model_name => todo_list_master.name } %></td>
  </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
</form>
```

So my goal, is to submit which checkbox's are checked and pass that to the new method in my controller. Obviously, I've wrapped that whole thing in the "form" tag, and so that's pretty much all I need. Any ideas about the best way to do this? Ajax or something maybe?

Also, as a quick side note, these elements don't actually reflect anything in the database, it's just JSON data I send.

Answer (score 0):

I've previously answered a similar question to this at the following link.

[HTTP Requests with Selection Checkboxes in Ruby on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21953729/favourite-functionality-ruby-on-rails/21954511#21954511)